# Make current explorer.exe window select a file

Tags: c#, explorer

my program runs on the background and I wanted it, given that I have explorer.exe windows open for example in My Music folder to select(Not open) "test.txt". But when I run my code(see below) It opens a new window with the file selected. I want it to just select the file, on the window that's already open.

Code:

```
string pathname = "c:\DocTest\Test.txt";
ProcessStartInfo l_psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
l_psi.Filename = "Explorer";
l_psi.Arguments = string.Format(@"/select, " + @ "" + pathname);
l_psi.UseShellExecute=true;
Process l_newProcess = new Process();
l.newProcess.StartInfo = l_psi;
l_newProcess.Start();
```

Please remember the two points:
-I don't want it to open the file, only to select it on a folder

-I don't want it to open a new explorer window, just use the one that's already open

Thanks for reading :)

Comment: Unless this is purely for your own use, this sounds like a bad design. A user can open *multiple* explorer windows and will tend to think of those windows as "theirs". You randomly hijacking *one* of those windows will not be a pleasant experience.

Comment: It's not done it that way, the way i designed it only applies to the foreground window.

Comment: I have a solution but I use Delphi. I can post it if it helps you.

Comment: It has to be in c#, but thanks anyway :)

Comment: Don't understand. Do you need my solution on don't? :)

Comment: I'm afraid it wouldn't work for me :/ I need it to be in c# not in Delphi, but thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

As found on [Microsoft Support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/130510)

> Syntax
>
> EXPLORER.EXE [/n][/e][,/root,][[,/select],]
>   Switches
>
> /n:  Opens a new window in single-paned (My Computer) view for each
>   item
>        selected, even if the new window duplicates a window that is
>        already open.
>
> /e:  Uses Windows Explorer view. Windows Explorer view is most similar
>        to File Manager in Windows version 3.x. Note that the default view
>        is Open view.
>
> /root,:  Specifies the root level of the specified view. The
>                    default is to use the normal namespace root (the
>                    desktop). Whatever is specified is the root for the
>                    display.
>
> /select,:  Specifies the folder to receive the initial
>                          focus. If "/select" is used, the parent folder
>                          is opened and the specified object is selected.

There is no mention of reusing an open Explorer, so it might not be possible.

Comment: I see, but there must be another way.. I'm not saying that I have to use the method I've shown before, but any other way is fine for me :b